# hibernate unknown entity when using hibernate 5 java 8

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

**when i want to save my object it throws unknown entity exception.**

tnx in advance

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown
>   entity: com.simpleProgrammer.User     at
>   org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:618)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:667)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:659)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:654)     at
>   com.simpleProgrammer.Program.main(Program.java:22)

**my hibernate.cfg.xml file is here**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <!--   <property name="hibernate.default_schema"></property> -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <mapping resource="com/simpleProgrammer/User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**my User.hbm.xml mapping file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.simpleProgrammer.User" table="USERS">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
        <component name="proteinData">
            <property name="total" column="TOTAL" type="int" />
            <property name="goal" column="GOAL" type="int" />
        </component>
        <set name="history" table="USER_HISTORY">
            <key column="ID"/>
            <composite-element class="com.simpleProgrammer.UserHistory">
                <property name="entryTime" type="date" column="ENTRY_TIME"/>
                <property name="entry" type="string" column="ENTRY"/>
            </composite-element>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my progaram.java

```
package com.simpleProgrammer;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = new HibernateUtilities().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println("Session Opened!!!");
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Transaction begined!");

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Joe");
        user.getHistory().add(new UserHistory(new Date(), "Setting Name to Joe"));
        user.getProteinData().setGoal(250);
        user.getHistory().add(new UserHistory(new Date(), "Setting Goal to 250!"));
        System.out.println("Setting user Object");
        session.save(user);
        System.out.println("Saving user object on table");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Transaction Commited!");

        session.beginTransaction();
        User loadedUser = session.get(User.class, 1);
        System.out.println(loadedUser.getName());
        System.out.println(loadedUser.getProteinData().getGoal());
        System.out.println(loadedUser.getProteinData().getTotal());
        loadedUser.getProteinData().setTotal(loadedUser.getProteinData().getTotal() + 50);
        loadedUser.getHistory().add(new UserHistory(new Date(), "Added 50 Protein!"));
        for (UserHistory history : loadedUser.getHistory()) {
            System.out.println(history.getEntryTime().toString() + " " + history.getEntry());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("Session Closed!!!");
        HibernateUtilities().getSessionFactory().close();
        System.out.println("Session Factory Closed");
    }
}
```

**user class**

```
package com.simpleProgrammer;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private ProteinData proteinData = new ProteinData();
    private Set<UserHistory> history =  new HashSet<UserHistory>();

    public Set<UserHistory> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }

    public void setHistory(Set<UserHistory> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ProteinData getProteinData() {
        return proteinData;
    }

    public void setProteinData(ProteinData proteinData) {
        this.proteinData = proteinData;
    }
}
```

[here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Pwa.jpg)

Comment: try this, it worked for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194384/exception-in-thread-main-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity

Comment: try this, it worked for me: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194384/exception-in-thread-main-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your other configure file."Unknown entity" means your application doesn't find something like User.hbm.xml in the path.

Comment: it worked before i add user history!
i think its somthing has to do with it.